# WPF Trigger based on DataGridCell Value Type

Tags: c#, wpf

What i am trying is

```
<local:class_converter_data_type x:Key="DataTypeConverter"/>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Converter={StaticResource DataTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
             <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
         </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
       
 public class class_converter_data_type : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return value?.GetType() ?? Binding.DoNothing;
       }
 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
   }
```

What errors i am making here? Binding format has any errors or in conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do it like this. The `DataGridCell` does not directly contain any type information of the underlying data type. The cleanest way is to listen to the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event and configure the appearance of the column's content:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

**MainWIndow.xaml.cs**

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
  if (e.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)) 
    && e.Column is DataGridTextColumn column)
  {
    column.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
  }
}
```

In case you are not auto-generating the columns, you can set the font style by setting the `DataGridTextColumn.FontStyle` XAML attribute.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn FontStyle="Italic" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, i havent figured it out DatagridCell contains textblock. Thanks a lot for instant help. I will use DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn event.

Comment: Yes, a TextBlock is implicitly created to show values after calling ToString() on non string types.